# Can't create GCP storage transfer job using API

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I am trying to create a Storage Transfer job using the API. I have tried using both the Python and the REST API. I had a number of issues with authentication, but after seeming to have solved those, when I submit the job now I get an error code 400 with the message "Precondition check failed" and status "FAILED_PRECONDITION".

I am at a loss to understand what precondition could be failing.

Here is the JSON I am sending. Note that the source and sink buckets are not in the sample-project. I am making the call from a Compute Engine instance in sample-project and authenticating with a service account using JSON credentials.

```
{
  "status": "ENABLED",
  "description": "sample-job-name",
  "transferSpec": {
    "gcsDataSource": {
      "bucketName": "source-bucket-name"
    },
    "transferOptions": {
      "deleteObjectsUniqueInSink": false,
      "overwriteObjectsAlreadyExistingInSink": false,
      "deleteObjectsFromSourceAfterTransfer": false
    },
    "gcsDataSink": {
      "bucketName": "sink-bucket-name"
    },
    "objectConditions": {
      "includePrefixes": [
        "sampleprefix/"
      ]
    }
  },
  "projectId": "sample-project-name",
  "schedule": {
    "scheduleStartDate": {
      "year": 2018,
      "day": 9,
      "month": 4
    },
    "scheduleEndDate": {
      "year": 2018,
      "day": 9,
      "month": 4
    }
  }
}
```

I've tried it with both the current date and a future date and it makes no difference. I've also tried it with different buckets, and with the project-id matching the project of the buckets. That doesn't change anything. Any ideas of what the failed precondition might mean would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The problem turns out to be the permissions for project-@storage-transfer-service.iam.gserviceaccount.com

The needed permissions are documented at https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/iam-transfer

Be careful setting these; I had set them in the first place, but apparently not correctly, and after I went back to looking at them it still took me a couple tries before it worked.